# Workaround for optional parameter with mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, optional-parameters

I'm trying to convert stored proc from mssql--> mysql. And stuck with optional parameters as mysql doesn't support it. For mssql the parameters are initialized to NULL and based on the p_Mode value different statements are being called.Is there a workaround for this? 
My converted MySQL stored proc is this :

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_tblLogin`(
    p_LoginId int/* =null */,
    p_LoginName varchar(100)/* =null */,
    p_Email varchar(100)/* =null */,
    p_Username varchar(20)/* =null */,
    p_Password varchar(20)/* =null */,
    p_Rights int/* =null */,
    p_Mode varchar(25))
    BEGIN

    IF (p_Mode='Insert') THEN 
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE Username=p_Username)
    THEN
        INSERT INTO tblLogin(LoginName,Email,Username,Password,Rights,ModifiedDate) VALUES(p_LoginName,p_Email,p_Username,p_Password,p_Rights,now());
    END IF;
    END IF;

    IF (p_Mode='View') 
    THEN
        SELECT * FROM tblLogin;
    END IF;

    IF (p_Mode='ViewByID') 
    THEN
        SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE LoginId = p_LoginId;
    END IF;

    IF (p_Mode='ChkLogin') 
    THEN
        SELECT * FROM tblLogin WHERE Username = p_Username and Password = p_Password;
    END IF;

    IF (p_Mode='Update') 
    THEN
        UPDATE tblLogin
        SET `LoginName` = p_LoginName
          ,`Email` = p_Email
          ,`Username` = p_Username
          ,`Password` = p_Password
          ,`Rights` = p_Rights
          ,`ModifiedDate` = now()
        WHERE LoginId = p_LoginId;
    END IF;

    IF (p_Mode='Delete') 
    THEN
        DELETE FROM `tblLogin` WHERE LoginId = p_LoginId;
    END IF;

    END
```

Comment: Seeing `VARCHAR(20)` for a password means this is a great opportunity for you to fix that and apply proper password hashing methods. At the absolute least you should be using [BCrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) which produces strings around 60 characters long.

Comment: I think even after that change my problem will persist. As mysql doesn't allow me to initialize parameters to NULL like MSSQL. While calling it from c# with just few parameters it keeps giving me error that 'parameter not found in collection'. Is there a way around for this?

Comment: Why don't you convert this all to application code? Using stored procedures like this is a mess. MySQL's stored procedures are really feeble compared to other RDBMS platforms like Oracle, Postgres or SQL Server.

Comment: Yes. I'm keeping that as my last option. Breaking the stored procedures and making new ones and then calling the exact stored procedure with exact parameters from the application side (C#). I was just wondering if someone out there knows any other way around! :)

Comment: It's not worth fixing. This is the sort of stuff a DBA does when they're afraid of writing application code. Don't do it. Write out your application logic in the application layer and keep your database as simple as possible. You won't regret it.